# Application and module name though JNDI in WebSphere 7

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jndi, websphere-7

I have an EAR application in a cell with two web modules, each web module has a servlet.

I want to get through JNDI the application and module name when I request each servlet.

I have tried with:

```
String applicationName = (String) new InitialContext()
    .lookup("java:app/AppName");

String moduleName = (String) new InitialContext()
    .lookup("java:module/ModuleName");
```

Did't work. **app** and **module**  are not found in **java:** .

I found this example in a webpage, maybe this works for WebSphere 8 but not for 7.

I tried to found an entry with the app or module name in **java:comp/env** but I didn't found any.

- How could I get the application name from the Application Server ?
- And the module name ?
- There is a better way than though JNDI ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

One way I can think of for application level would be to specify an `<env-entry>` in the web.xml of your application. Websphere will ask you to specify the value on deployment but it will use whatever you put in web.xml as the default.

For example:

```
<env-entry>
    <env-entry-name>AppName</env-entry-name>
    <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
    <env-entry-value>MyApp</env-entry-value>
</env-entry>
```

Then you can look this value up through JNDI using `java:comp/env/AppName`.

Comment: I can't think of a per-module way of doing it at the moment.

Comment: This could be a turnaround. But if two instances of the same application are deployed in the same server with the same value I will have a conflict for my use case. But if I could get the application name from WebSphere there will be no conflict.

Comment: Correct, with this method you would have to specify the unique name for the application. WebSphere will ask you to provide this value at deploy-time but it will use what is in web.xml as the default. I don't know if WS automatically registers any names to the local and/or java context.

Comment: Here's a couple of links I found about dumping the JNDI context using wsadmin... haven't been able to find something like you describe but thought you might be interested: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.express.doc%2Finfo%2Fexp%2Fae%2Ftnam_view_bindings.html  http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.express.doc%2Finfo%2Fexp%2Fae%2Frnam_dump_utility_java_local.html